# How to show that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus k_{2,3}\#-k_{2,3})\not\cong\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus k_{2,3}\# k_{2,3})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

How to show that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus k_{2,3}\#-k_{2,3})\not\cong\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus k_{2,3}\# k_{2,3})$ by their presentations?

Here $k_{2,3}$ stands for the trefoil knot. $k_{2,3}\#-k_{2,3}$ stands for the connected sum of $k_{2,3}$ with its mirror image, and $k_{2,3}\# k_{2,3}$ stands for the connected sum of $k_{2,3}$ with itself.

I have no difficulty finding their presentations:

$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus k_{2,3}\#-k_{2,3})\cong\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\mid a_1a_2a_1=a_2a_1a_2,\ a_3a_4a_3=a_4a_3a_4,\ a_2=a_4a_3a_4^{-1}\rangle$$
$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus k_{2,3}\#k_{2,3})\cong\langle b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\mid b_1b_2b_1=b_2b_1b_2,\ b_3b_4b_3=b_4b_3b_4,\ b_2=b_4^{-1}b_3b_4\rangle$$

But I'm in great trouble showing that they are **not** isomorphic. I rarely dealt with such problems, and the long complex equations are disturbing to me. By the way, they are really **not** isomorphic, right?

Any hint, method or solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may come as a surprise: these two groups are isomorphic!

Here's the general idea (with a concrete calculation with your presentations at the end).  For a connect sum $K_1\mathbin{\#} K_2$ of knots, there is a ball $B\subset S^3$ whose boundary $\partial B$ intersects $K_1\mathbin{\#} K_2$ in exactly two points, where $B\cap (K_1\mathbin\# K_2)$ is the "$K_1$" part of the connect sum.  The complement $X_1=B- \nu(K_1\mathbin\# K_2)$ is homeomorphic to $S^3-\nu(K_1)$, preserving orientations, where $\nu(K_1\mathbin\# K_2)\subset S^3$ denotes a tubular neighborhood of the connect sum.  Similarly, $X_2=\overline{S^3-B}-\nu(K_1\mathbin\# K_2)$ is homeomorphic, preserving orientations, to $S^3-\nu(K_2)$.  ($\overline{S^3-B}$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball.)

So, $S^3-\nu(K_1\mathbin\# K_2)=X_1\cup X_2$ with $X_1\cap X_2$ being an annulus $A$. By the van Kampen theorem, $\pi_1(S^3-\nu(K_1\mathbin\# K_2))$ is the amalgamated free product $\pi_1(X_1)*_A\pi_1(X_2)$.  The image of the generator for $\pi_1(A)$ in $\pi_1(X_1)$ and $\pi_1(X_2)$ are two consistently-oriented meridians for the respective knot complement.  (An "oriented meridian" is one that links positively with the knot, given the knot's orientation.)

Let $-\overline{K_2}$ indicate the mirror image of the inverse of the knot.  The inverse is the knot with inverted orientation (remember: the connect sum of two knots depends on the orientation of the two knots in general --- many small knots, like the trefoil, are isotopic to their inverse).  The mirror image map $S^3\to S^3$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(S^3-K_2)\to \pi_1(S^3-(-\overline{K_2}))$ that sends an oriented meridian to an oriented meridian.

With $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ being respective meridians for $K_1$ and $K_2$, $$\pi_1(S^3-\nu(K_1\mathbin\#K_2))\approx\left(\pi_1(S^3-K_1)*\pi_1(S^3-K_2)\right)/\langle \mu_1\mu_2^{-1}\rangle$$
Using the above comments about mirror images of inverses, this is also
$$\left(\pi_1(S^3-K_1)*\pi_1(S^3-(-\overline{K_2}))\right)/\langle \mu_1\mu_2^{-1}\rangle\approx \pi_1(S^3-\nu(K_1\mathbin\# -\overline{K_2}))$$
In your case, the trefoil $k_{2,3}$ is isotopic to its inverse,
so
$$\pi_1(S^3-k_{2,3}\mathbin\#k_{2,3}) \approx \pi_1(S^3-(k_{2,3}\mathbin\#-k_{2,3})).$$
(I'm just using your notation.  I think mirror images are usually denoted with an overline or by prefixing with an $m$.)

Concretely, there is an isomorphism
$$\pi_1(S^3-(k_{2,3}\mathbin\#-k_{2,3})) \to \pi_1(S^3-k_{2,3}\mathbin\#k_{2,3}) $$ which we can give in the following way.
Since I don't knot exactly how you got your particular presentations, I recomputed the fundamental groups:

[image: Fundamental group calculations]

Notice that $a_1a_3=a_3a_2=a_2a_4=a_4a_3$, so $a_1=a_4$.  This corresponds to the generator of the fundamental group of the annulus separating the two knot exteriors:

[image: Annulus separating knot exteriors]

Using the first three relations, we can calculate $a_1a_2a_1=a_2a_1a_2$, and with the last three, $a_1a_5a_1=a_5a_1a_5$.  Hence,
$$\pi_1(S^3-(k_{2,3}\mathbin\#k_{2,3}))\approx \langle a_1,a_2,a_5\mid a_1a_2a_1=a_2a_1a_2,a_1a_5a_1=a_5a_1a_5\rangle.$$
Doing the same thing for the second knot, you get
$$\pi_1(S^3-(k_{2,3}\mathbin\#-k_{2,3}))\approx \langle b_1,b_2,b_5\mid b_1b_2b_1=b_2b_1b_2,b_1b_5b_1=b_5b_1b_5\rangle.$$
So the homomorphism defined by $a_1\mapsto b_1$, $a_2\mapsto b_2$, and $a_3\mapsto b_3$ is an isomorphism.

---

Waldhausen proved that $\pi_1(S^3-K)$, along with the *peripheral subgroup* generated by a meridian and a longitude, determines $K$.  Your example shows why the fundamental group of the complement is not sufficient.

Comment: Oh god they are not isomorphic... Thank you for your answer, but I can't really understand most of the argument for I'm quite unfamiliar with $S^3$. Maybe I should just try verifying the map is an isomorphism. I did think about that map, but I didn't think that was an isomorphism. The verification is still not obvious for me right now, but I'll try it. And maybe I should figure out another way to show the two knots are not ambient isotopic...

Comment: If you remove a single point, $S^3$ becomes $\mathbb{R}^3$. This doesn't change fundamental groups. The three-sphere just makes arguments more symmetric. If you switch everything to $\mathbb{R}^3$, just keep in mind that the complement of a ball is a punctured ball.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll try to visualise it in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Hey I think $a_4\mapsto b_4^{-1}$ would not give an isomorphism: $b_3b_4b_3=b_4b_3b_4$ along with $b_2=b_4^{-1}b_3b_4$ gives $b_4=b_3^{-1}b_2b_3$ while $a_3a_4a_3=a_4a_3a_4$ along with $a_2=a_4a_3a_4^{-1}$ gives $a_4=a_3a_2a_3^{-1}\mapsto b_4^{-1}=b_3b_2b_3^{-1}$ , thus if it is an isomorphism there would be $b_3b_2b_3^{-1}=b_3^{-1}b_2^{-1}b_3\Rightarrow b_2b_3^2 b_2=b_3^2$, which actually comes from nowhere.

Comment: Oh, you're right -- I guess I was too confident in the theory to check the details!  I just redid the fundamental group calculations, used some of the theory to simplify the presentation, and then got a pair of identical group presentations.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that I killed wrong variables.